# Automator mac "Take Screenshot" issue

Tags: automator

I need to automate a screenshot task, so I thought why not use automator? I found the "Take Screenshot" Action and started to play with it. The problem is is that is sets the file name and when the workflow is ran again it overwrites the prior screenshot. I tried selecting this and renaming it but it wont work. Essentially what I want is the normal function of command + shift + 3 where it will date-stamp it or something, anything but overwrite!! Any ideas?

Comment: This is probably better suited to apple.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to use screencapture and date to do something similar:

```
fdate=$(date +"$m$d$Y") #I formatted time as mmddyyyy. You can use other formats, add dashes, etc.
screencapture -iW ~/$fdate.png   #outputs file at ~/mmddyyyy.png
```

or something like that. You could wrap this into a shell workflow, or put it in the popular wrapper for OSX, Platypus. I'd seriously like to know how to do that, since I've never been able to understand Platypus.

Answer (score 0):

I took the answer from @user8259 and made it more like the built-in screen capture that you normally see:

```
# We'll use the default format for the time-stamp
# This could be improved to be more like the Mac's built-in
# screen-shot with yyyy-mm-dd at hh.mm.ss AM/PM
# you would just have to figure out the date-time formatting
# in this shell script.
theTime=`date`

# create the file name for the screen-shot
theFileName="$HOME/Desktop/Screenshot $theTime.png"

#outputs file on the Desktop with a timestamp
screencapture "${theFileName}"
```

My version of the code includes a time-stamp in addition to the date-stamp to make it less likely that a screen-shot will overwrite a previous screen shot.

You can add this code to an Automator action called the "Run Shell Script" action instead of using the "Take Screenshot" action.